# Condensing a Subquery When Correlated Subquery Doesn't Work

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the lengthy subquery in here. Is there a way to condense this?

```
SELECT 
      Count(TicketNbr) AS [Tickets Entered]

      -- SUBQUERY HERE
      ,     (SELECT AVG(hours_actual)
            FROM dbo.Service
            WHERE
            [company_name] LIKE 'XYZ'
            AND [status_description] NOT IN ('>Cancelled', 'Duplicate')
            AND hours_actual >= 0.1
            )

      FROM dbo.Service
      WHERE 
      [company_name] LIKE 'XYZ'
      AND [status_description] NOT IN ('>Cancelled', 'Duplicate')
```

I tried to use correlated subquery but this requires that TicketNbr
be GROUPed in the outer query.  I don't want that.

This doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
      Count(TicketNbr) AS [Tickets Entered]

      -- SUBQUERY HERE
      ,     (SELECT AVG(hours_actual)
            FROM dbo.Service AS [Y]
            WHERE Y.TicketNbr = X.TicketNbr
            AND Y.hours_actual >= 0.1

            )

      FROM dbo.Service AS [X]
      WHERE 
      [company_name] LIKE 'XYZ'
      AND [status_description] NOT IN ('>Cancelled', 'Duplicate')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same with a simple case expression:

```
SELECT   Count(TicketNbr) AS [Tickets Entered]
,        AVG(CASE WHEN hours_actual >= 0.1 THEN hours_actual END)
FROM dbo.Service AS [X]
WHERE [company_name] LIKE 'XYZ'
  AND [status_description] NOT IN ('>Cancelled', 'Duplicate')
```

Comment: Thank you! Completely forgot CASE can be used within aggregrate functions!